# register/unregister a service through the toggle button more than once

Tags: android, dynamic, android-service, togglebutton

This is what my code is... and I am getting a problem because of registering and unregistering(multiple times) my receiver(which is starting a service).

the problem is that: i have seen that the 'receiver' variable becomes NULL after once executing registerReceiver and unregisterReceiver commands... specifically, after I register and unregister and then again register the receiver, the receiver has NULL only, and hence, while unregistering it again, it gives an error! so basically, my app is not able to register a Receiver again after unregistering it once. why is that a problem?

```
public class startScreen  extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
        serviceIntent.setAction("com.example.MyService");
        context.startService(serviceIntent);

    }

    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.initial);

       final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE");



      Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      final ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
      try
    {
                 ... some code...             
      if(bool == true)
      {
        toggleButton.setChecked(true);
        this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
      }
      else
          toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }catch(Exception e) {
           Log.e("Error", "Database", e);
          } finally {
                         ...
          }

      toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {        
          public void onClick(View v) {
              if((toggleButton.isChecked()))
              {
                  getBaseContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

              }
              else
              {
                  if (receiver != null){
                      getBaseContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
                         receiver = null;
            }

              }
          }
    });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
              if(bool == true)
              {
               if(receiver == null)
                   this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
              }                       
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    if (receiver != null){
        this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        receiver = null;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly setting `receiver` to null inside `toggleButton.setOnClickListener` and in `onPause`:

```
receiver = null;
```

Try removing those lines and see if it fixes the issue

Comment: ok will try to do that, but then how would you check if the service is regitered or not, at any given instance in the code?

Comment: You could store a `boolean` that you track instead. That way you maintain a the receiver instance.